# Difference between "parecer" and "parecerse a"

Tags: verbo-pronominal

Is there any difference in meaning between "parecer" and "parecerse a"? Example:

- Eso no parece una barricada.
- Eso no se parece a una barricada.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these sentences in English:

- This doesn't appear to be a pumpkin. [Context: someone tried to make a Jack-o-Lantern by carving a gourd, or a honeydew melon.]
- This doesn't look like a pumpkin. [Context: someone painted a pumpkin white and drew cat features on it.  The result is interesting.  Even though it started out as a pumpkin, it now no longer looks like one.  I saw this today in a Martha Stewart magazine in a waiting room.]

To be able to clarify your two proposed sentences in a precise way, we would need some context.  But hopefully my two examples can open you up to some of the possibilities.

Comment: As my examples don't have the verb "ser", I didn't understand the analogy with "appear to be". Is it related to "parecer" or "parecerse" ?

Comment: "Appear to be" is expressed in Spanish as "parecer" or "parece ser." "Se parece a" means "[Subject] looks like (is similar to)".  Actually, come to think of it, regarding your first bullet, I think I would rather say, "Eso no parece ser una barricada" in most contexts (but maybe not all).